# NSTableCellView / NSTextField did end editing notification -- without text change?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

How can I get a notification when the textfield has ended editing (enter key pressed, clicked outside the text field, clicked inside the same column, but outside the text field, etc)

I checked

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   //some code here
}
```

but this notification is only called when the text has actually changed. I need to be notified even if no text changes have been made.

Edit: Some sort of notification that the first responder has changed would work as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the `firstResponder` state of the window …

```
…
[theWindow addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstResponder" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
…
```

… and read the field editor's delegate:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"firstResponder"])
  {
    NSResponder *oldResponder =change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    if ([oldResponder isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]])
    {
      NSTextView *editor = (NSTextView*)oldResponder;
      NSTextField *textField = (NSTextField*)editor.delegate;
      NSLog(@"This text field lost the focus: %@", textField.identifier);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears that this is called when the textfield is focussed, not when it looses focus, although I set `options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld`. Can you imagine why?

Comment: It is not called or do jump over an if statement? Please, set a breakpoint to the first `if`.

Comment: As I commented; there is no if when I don't mention it ;-) Strange enough, isn't it?

Comment: It is strange. "In OS X v10.6 and later, firstResponder is key-value observing compliant." The option is without any meaning, because the are options for the passed data, not for the event, that sends the message. Have to make a test project, but do not have enough time today.

Comment: This really drives me nuts and I don't get why... I mean I'm getting notifs for the last responder, so it does work, but not completely...

Comment: When an NSTextField receives focus, it immediately creates a field editor (an NSTextView) and gives that keyboard focus. So NSTextFields never have keyboard focus while they're being edited. Could that be the weird behaviour you are seeing?